# Asymptotic variance covariance matrix of maximum likelihood estimate of Pareto distribution

Tags: maximum-likelihood, pareto-distribution, asymptotic-covariance

I have some problem deriving the asymptotic variance-covariance matrix for MLE of the pareto distribution and hope to receive help.

Consider random variable $X$ follows Pareto distribution, where
$f_X(x) = \frac{a \lambda^a}{x^{a+1}}, \quad x \ge \lambda$

The loglikelihood function is $l(x|\lambda, a) = n\ln a + na\ln \lambda - (a+1) \sum \ln x_i $

The first order derivatives are

$\frac{\partial l}{\partial a} = \frac{n}{a} + n\ln \lambda - \sum \ln X_i$ or $\hat{a} = \frac{n}{\sum \ln x_i - n\ln \hat{\lambda}}$

$\frac{\partial l}{\partial \lambda} = \frac{na}{\lambda}$ or $\hat{\lambda} = x_{min}$

The second order derivatives are:

$\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial a^2} = \frac{-n}{a^2}$

$\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial \lambda^2} = \frac{-na}{\lambda^2}$

$\frac{\partial^2 l}{\partial a \partial \lambda} = \frac{n}{\lambda}$

The Hessian matrix is

$Hessian_{2\times 2} = \begin{bmatrix}
 \frac{-n}{a^2} & \frac{n}{\lambda} \cr
 \frac{n}{\lambda} & \frac{-na}{\lambda^2} 
\end{bmatrix}$

I know that to compute the asymptotic variance-covariance matrix, I need to take expected value of the negative of the Hessian (which will give me the information matrix). Then I need to compute the inverse of the information matrix to get the var-cov matrix.

However, when take expectation of negative of the Hessian with respect to $x$, I cannot derive the information matrix similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution

Could someone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341085/finding-asymptotic-variance-of-mle-using-fisher-information-comprehension-of-s.